# In Scala, how do I extend an object with multiple classes?

Tags: scala, multiple-inheritance

How do I inject `App` into an `object` already being extended by another?

```
object Foo extends SomeClass with Bar {
    /* imports */
    /* <-- Want code here to be run as if within `main` scope --> */   
}
```

Basically I want to take advantage of the `App` main class ([example](http://ideone.com/PZlmFK)); without which I receive this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
```

(So don't need to worry about defining my own `def main (args : Array[String])`)

Comment: App is not a class. It's a trait as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not `object Foo extends SomeClass with Bar with App`? [App is a trait](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.App), so it could be mixed into class effortlessly.

Answer (score 1):

In scala you can extend from one class and many traits. Since App is actually a trait what you want is possible and you could do something like

```
object Foo extends MyClass with App {
}
```